# small cap i for 1

Tags: numbering, small-caps

In the documentation of `biblatex` and `csquotes` packages, number `1` is replaced by a small cap `i` in the main text. I tried to find how in the source files but could not target any relevant piece of code. It looks like one way would be to define a `\DeclareTextCommand{\is}{T1}{\textsc{i}{}}` and then use `\is978` in the source but in the mentioned documents, `1` is directly redefined as the new character (looking like) `\textsc{i}`.

Comment: It's not a small caps "i"; it's how the Charter font renders the 1.

Comment: haaaa, too bad. Still, for other fonts, is there an easy way to get what I am asking for?

Comment: You could replace every `1` by a smallcaps `i` by making it active. For instance `\catcode\`1\active\def1{\textsc{i}}` would do that. This could cause issues though, if some packages uses a `1` in a command sequence or something like that. So you have to consider that.

Comment: @RoelofSpijker Now that's just mean. ;-)

Comment: @RoelofSpijker You could do that, but it's a 'Do Not Do This' answer :-)

Comment: yes, I tried for the fun. That's too bad that we cannot have '1' active for a given purpose only!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a small caps i, it is an old-style number 1. One way to get this is by using `XeLaTeX` and setting the main font to use old style numbers.

Most fonts (in my limited experience) do not have an old-style numeral 1 that looks like what you want. I think that the font used in the `biblatex` package documentation that gives the character you want is called [Charter](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/charter/).

[image: example output]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xltxtra, fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Charter} %this is where you select the font
\begin{document}

Old style: 0123456789\\

\end{document}
```